# al generar un numero random y generarlo de vuelta da el mismo PYTHON 3.8.1

Tags: python, python-3.x

mi codigo genera un numero random para que lo adivines pero al jugar de vuelta (GENERAR OTRO NUMERO RANDOM PARA HACER OTRO JUEGO) solo se usa el mismo numero y la generacion de otro queda nula(no se ejecuta)

pd: estoy haciendo un juego que se podra descargar en github

pregunten y paso link de github (escribo esto para añadir detalles)

CUALQUIER PREGUNTA SERA RESPONDIDA DE INMEDIATO (1 - 10 minutos)

mi codigo de un adivina el numero pero con numeros random

```
from random import randrange
import os

def cerrar_juego():
  print("quiere jugar otra vez?")
  o = input("(s/n) ")
  if o == "s":
   os.system("cls")
   x = randrange(0, 50) # y aqui el otro

   if x < 20 or x == 20:
    lvl1()

   if x > 20 and x < 30:
    lvl2() 

   if x > 30 or x == 50:
    lvl3()

def lvl1():


      print("el numero esta entre 0 y 20")
      adv = int(input("pon un numero : "))
      if adv == x:
        print("lo has logrado!!!")
        os.system("cls")
        cerrar_juego()

      if adv < x:
        print("pon mas la proxima")
        lvl1()

      if adv > x:
        print("pon menos la proxima")
        lvl1()



def lvl2():
  print("el numero esta entre 0 y 30")
  adv = int(input("pon un numero : "))
  if adv == x:
   print("lo has logrado!!!")
   os.system("cls")
   cerrar_juego()

  if adv < x:
   print("pon mas la proxima")
   lvl1()

  if adv > x:
   print("pon menos la proxima")
   lvl1()


def lvl3():
  print("el numero esta entre 0 y 50")
  adv = int(input("pon un numero : "))
  if adv == x:
   print("lo has logrado!!!")
   os.system("cls")
   cerrar_juego()

  if adv < x:
   print("pon mas la proxima")
   lvl1()

  if adv > x:
   print("pon menos la proxima")
   lvl1()




x = randrange(0, 50) # aqui genera el primer numero random

if x < 20:
  lvl1()

if x > 20 and x < 30:
    lvl2()

if x > 30:
  lvl3()
```

el codigo no da error solo que no ejecuta la parte de randomizar de vuelta la variable X

solo pasa al querer jugar de vuelta PORQUE NO GENERA EL NUEVO NUMERO RANDOM

Comment: ¿Cómo has comprobado que no llega a la línea del `randrange` en la función `cerrar_juego`? ¿Has puesto un print para saber los valores de `x`? Con un código con tantas interllamadas entre las funciones es difícil de seguir el flujo de ejecución. En python no es bueno para el stack de llamadas, además de que deberías evitar tantas repeticiones de código similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que estas asignando valor a variables diferentes aunque se llaman igual:

- Con la primera asignacion de valor a x estas creando una variable global
- En la segunda asignacion de valor a x en la funcion cerrar_juego() esta definiciendo una nueva variable x el ambito de la cual es solamente esa funcion

Por eso en las otras funciones lvlX el valor de x continua siendo el original

Para que en cerrar_juego() puedas modificar el valor de la variable global la tienes que declarar de esta manera

```
...
def cerrar_juego()
    global x
    ...
```